# How do I get the loess() function to run faster on my laptop

Tags: r

I’m trying to calculate local regression on R using the loess() function and the computer is taking forever to process it. 
How do I make it work faster?
My laptop has 8 GB RAM and a quad core processor

Comment: Please post an example of your code

Comment: Splines with `mgcv::gam` will generate a similar result but much more efficiently if you have large data.

Answer (score 0):

**Multi-threading in Caret.**

Step 1: Detect the number of logical cores on your computer.

```
library(doParallel)

detectCores(all.tests = FALSE, logical = TRUE)
```

Step 2: Assign more cores by changing the value inside makePSOCKcluster()

```
cl <- makePSOCKcluster(5)

registerDoParallel(cl)
```

Step 3: Inside carets *"trainControl"* set *"allowParallel = TRUE"*

Step 4: When you are finished multi-threading

```
stopCluster(cl)
```